# VS Code Unity - Summary on Hover not showing for methods with parameters

Tags: unity-game-engine, visual-studio-code

VSCode has this behavior where it'll show the summary on hover if it is directly before the method, like

```
//
// Summary:
//     Does something.
public void DoesAThing(){...}
```

However, it won't show a summary on hover if there's additional documentation (parameters, returns etc), like

```
//
// Summary:
//     Does something with a speed value
//
// Parameters:
//   speed:
//     How fast are you?
public void DoesSomething(int speed){...}
```

Is there any way to fix/change this behaviour so that these extended details can be shown? Almost all inbuilt Unity methods with parameters are documented this way, so it's rather inconvenient to not be able to see the descriptions.